# Problemas no netbeans com conexão com Postgres

Tags: java, swing, jpa, crud

Tenho um banco chamado BANCO_DE_TESTES no Postgres e que possui algumas tabelas aleatórias.  No netbeans quando eu tento usar o  Form de Amostras Mestre/Detalhe para usar o JPA para criar um simples crud ele não funciona dizendo que o banco que eu especifiquei não tem entidades(tabelas).
Mas quando eu vou na aba de serviços do netbeans e faço uma coneção com esse banco ele abre normalmente todas as tabelas do banco em questão (BANCO_DE_TESTES) e permite fazer qualquer tipo de consulta sobre elas!!!!

O que devo fazer?
 Com o mysql não tem bronca!!! Mas eu quero usar o Postgres!!!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui eu abro normalmente como vocês podem conferir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quanto ao Netbeans não sei dizer, qual o problema.

Mas um dos motivos pode ser que esteja acessando o schema errado.

> Porém para criar tabelas com JPA, precisa apenas criar o banco de
>   dados e o JPA com Hibernate por exemplo, se encarrega de criar as
>   tabelas conforme as classes anotadas, isso caso estiver utilizando
>   DDL.

Gerar código nunca é recomendado, se não funciona, tente criar manualmente.

Mapeando as classes que quiser criar e tendo seu CRUD em um DAO.

```
  @Entity
  public class Usuario {

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "usuarios_seq")
     @SequenceGenerator(name = "usuarios_seq", sequenceName = "usuarios_id_seq")
     private Long id;

     private String nome;
     private String email;
     private String senha;

     //getters e setters
  }
```

Agora a classe DAO com um CRUD

```
public class UsuarioDao {

        private EntityManager entityManager;

        public UsuarioDao() {
            entityManager = getEntityManager(); //Ex: Recebe um EntityManager pelo construtor
        }

        public Usuario usuarioPorId(int id) {
            return entityManager.find(Usuario.class, id);
        }

        public List<Usuario> todosUsuarios() {
            return entityManager.createQuery("SELECT u FROM Usuario u", Usuario.class).getResultList();
        }

        public void gravar(Usuario usuario) {
            try {
                entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
                entityManager.persist(usuario);
                entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                entityManager.getTransaction().rollback();
            }
        }

        public void atualizar(Usuario usuario) {
            try {
                entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
                entityManager.merge(usuario);
                entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                entityManager.getTransaction().rollback();
            }
        }

        public void remover(Usuario usuario) {
            try {
                entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
                usuario = entityManager.find(Usuario.class, usuario.getId());
                entityManager.remove(usuario);
                entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                entityManager.getTransaction().rollback();
            }
        }
    }
```